# Retrofit call adapter: randomly receiving Result<Result<Exception>>

Tags: android, retrofit2

I created a Retrofit call adapter to wrap my responses in Kotlin Result class, and return Result with exception when the request fails. But very rarely, when an IOException happens, I receive not Result.Failure with Exception inside, but Result.Success<Result.Failure> with Exception inside.

```
interface UserEndpoint {

    @Headers(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
    )
    @GET("rest/x")
    suspend fun loadX(): Result<X>
}

internal class NetworkResponseCall<S : Any>(
    private val delegate: Call<S>,
    private val retrofit: Retrofit
) : Call<Result<S>> {

    override fun enqueue(callback: Callback<Result<S>>) {
        return delegate.enqueue(object : Callback<S> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<S>, response: Response<S>) {
                //...
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<S>, throwable: Throwable) {
                val networkResponse = when (throwable) {
                    is IOException -> Result.failure<S>(NetworkException(throwable))
                    else -> Result.failure<S>(UnknownException(throwable))
                }
                val response = Response.success(networkResponse)
                callback.onResponse(this@NetworkResponseCall, response)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun isExecuted() = delegate.isExecuted

    override fun clone() = NetworkResponseCall(delegate.clone(), retrofit)

    override fun isCanceled() = delegate.isCanceled

    override fun cancel() = delegate.cancel()

    override fun execute(): Response<Result<S>> {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("NetworkResponseCall doesn't support execute")
    }

    override fun request(): Request = delegate.request()

    override fun timeout(): Timeout = delegate.timeout()

}

class ResultCallAdapter<S : Any>(
    private val successType: Type,
    private val retrofit: Retrofit
) : CallAdapter<S, Call<Result<S>>> {

    override fun responseType(): Type = successType

    override fun adapt(call: Call<S>): Call<Result<S>> {
        return NetworkResponseCall(call, retrofit) //, errorBodyConverter
    }
}

class ResultCallAdapterFactory : CallAdapter.Factory() {

    override fun get(
        returnType: Type,
        annotations: Array<Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): CallAdapter<*, *>? {
        if (Call::class.java != getRawType(returnType)) {
            return null
        }
        check(returnType is ParameterizedType) {
            "return type must be parameterized as Call<NetworkResponse<<Foo>> or Call<NetworkResponse<out Foo>>"
        }

        val responseType = getParameterUpperBound(0, returnType)
        if (getRawType(responseType) != Result::class.java) {
            return null
        }

        check(responseType is ParameterizedType) { "Response must be parameterized as Result<Foo> or Result<out Foo>" 
}

        val successBodyType = getParameterUpperBound(0, responseType
        return ResultCallAdapter<Any>(successBodyType, retrofit)
    }
}
```

The caller of loadX() occasionally receives Result.Success<Result.Failure> and this is poorly reproducible. I would be grateful for any help with this issue.

I tried logging what is passed here in NetworkResponseCall: callback.onResponse(this@NetworkResponseCall, response), but it's always the same value, in both good and bad cases.

**UPD: If I do not do frequent retries of requests, I do not see any reproduction of this issue at all. Around 1000 ms between retries removes it.**

**UPD: Changing Kotlin Result to my custom Result class removes the issue.**

UPD: I am basing my work on the example from this article https://proandroiddev.com/create-retrofit-calladapter-for-coroutines-to-handle-response-as-states-c102440de37a which refers to this github https://github.com/mlegy/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-call-adapter with a lot of stars and forks. So I think conceptually using Response.success in onFailure() is a working option which lets Retrofit know that it needs not to throw an exception, but return Result.Failure normally.

Comment: What is the exception that's being wrapped when this happens?

Comment: @GabeSechan it's NetworkException:

class NetworkException(override val cause: Throwable) : Exception() {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "NetworkException cause=$cause"
    }
}

Comment: @GabeSechan and also reproducible with just java.net.UnknownHostException that is being originally thrown

Answer (score 0):

```
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<S>, throwable: Throwable) {
            val networkResponse = when (throwable) {
                is IOException -> Result.failure<S>(NetworkException(throwable))
                else -> Result.failure<S>(UnknownException(throwable))
            }
            val response = Response.success(networkResponse)
            callback.onResponse(this@NetworkResponseCall, response)
        }
```

That's what's doing it.  This is the failure handler.  You're returning Response.success(networkResponse).  Where networkResponse in this case we know is a failure. You just want to pass in networkResponse to the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot pass just networkResponse. The onResponse callback accepts anyway Response (which I can create with Response.success or Response.error). Passing Response.error would not help me with returning Result.failure. I was initially following this example: https://proandroiddev.com/create-retrofit-calladapter-for-coroutines-to-handle-response-as-states-c102440de37a.

And my issue occurs very irregularly, most of the times the result is correct. I also do not want to call callback.onFailure instead of callback.onResponse, that would throw the exception, not pass back the result

Comment: Well then you'll need to adjust the return value until you're happy with it.  But written like this, whenever the onFailure is called it WILL return Response.success<Response.Failure>.  This would have been easily caught if you had a unit test for this class.

Comment: I would not agree about "whenever", the reproduction here is like 1 out of around 20 calls Result.Success<Result.Failure<Exception>>, all the other times correct - Result<Failure<Exception>>.

I would put the question like this: is there a way to receive Result.Failure<Exception> as a guaranteed value in case of Exception? I do not see any way to pass it other than this.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how Retrofit wants to work.  The callback.onResponse is supposed to be called only when a valid HTTP response is returned.  There is a callback.onFailure that takes an exception.  Use that.